# How to get Cart Id and Subtotal in sales_order_save_after observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I have to call some API on order status **complete**. For that I need values for the following.

- credit card number (16 digits).
- CVV
- subtotal
- and I have already called an API while place order I need to pass some of the response of that API here.

and my code is below

```
 public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); 
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

        if($order->getState() == "complete") 
        { 

           $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
           $cart = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
           $payment = $order->getPayment();
           $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
           $creditCardNumber =  $payment->getCcNumber();
           $CCV = $payment->getCcCid();
           $SubtotalAmount =(double)$cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
           $Rate = $_SESSION["rate"];//This is the response of API called on place order.

        }
```

for the above code my output is

- credit card number = null (if i use getCcLast4() its working, but i want full 16 digits number).
- CVV  = null
- subtotal = 0
- and I have already called an API while place order I need to pass some of the response of that API here. = log error.

can any one help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 doesn't  store customer's `credit card` number or `CCV` number.

It's against **PCI standards** to keep customer credit card info in your database. You can find the reasons why PCI Council restricts this in the post - http://blog.emagicone.com/2015/12/why-credit-cards-can-not-be-charged.html

**Edit**

I think, cart object is not require because you have `$order` instance already. So you can get order sub-total by `$order->getSubTotal()`.

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

    if ($order->getState() == "complete") {
        /*
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory');
        */
        $payment = $order->getPayment();
        $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
        $creditCardNumber = $payment->getCcNumber();
        $CCV = $payment->getCcCid();
        /*
        $SubtotalAmount = (double)$cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
        */
        $SubtotalAmount = $order->getSubtotal();
        $Rate = $_SESSION["rate"];//This is the response of API called on place order.
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i get subtotal?

Comment: @ASHWINIMURTHY check my update

Comment: Thanks. now iam able to get subtotal, but still my creditcard number and CVV is null...

Comment: i mentioned why couldn't you get  these information.

Comment: yeah i went through, how can i get Cart id?

Answer (score 0):

I Got cart Id in my sales_order_save_after observer using quote Id

`$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
CartId = $order->getQuoteId();`